# Factory in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, runtime-error, factory

Im trying to use a factory in angularJS, but I don't work as expected.

Here is my controller:

```
as.controller('Test', ['testFactory', function($scope, $http, $rootScope)
{   

    $http.get($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/test/test')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.test = data;
    });

    $scope.form = {};

    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
        if(isValid) 
        {   
            testFactory.testFactoryMethod(function($http) {
                $scope.test = data;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

As you can see, I "include" my factory to the controller.

Here is my factory:

```
.factory('testFactory', function($http) {
    return {
            testFactoryMethod: function(callback) {
                return $http('http://127.0.0.1:81/test/test', data).success(function(data) { callback(data);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

When I run this, I get this error message:

```
Error: $http is undefined
@http://127.0.0.1:82/nao/js/controllers.js:82:3
```

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're forgetting the $http.post:

$http(url, data) should be $http.post(url, data)

And what others have said before, you need the testFactory injected in the controllers function.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because of Angular [$injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector). When you provide an array as 2nd argument for `.controller`, the `$injector` tries to find all dependencies listed on it by their name and then inject them to the array's last element (which must be a `function`), so in your case, this is what happens:

```
'testFactory' -> $scope
undefined -> $http
undefined -> $rootScope
```

Your code should be either like this:

```
as.controller('Test', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'testFactory', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, testFactory)
{
    // ...
```

... or like this:

```
as.controller('Test', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, testFactory)
{
    // ...
```

**Edit:** As @sp00m stated, the second example should not be used if you are going to uglify (minify) your code, because the uglifier algorithm will replace those identifiers with something like:

```
function(a, b, c, d)
```

And then AngularJS will not be able to find those dependencies anymore, whereas the first example would look like this:

```
['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'testFactory', function(a, b, c, d)
```

Which is valid, because you are explicitly telling Angular which dependencies it must inject.

Comment: Better use the first syntax, you may have problems with the second one if you *uglify* your code.

Comment: I'm glad to help. Also consider reading [`$injector` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector).

Comment: @DaniloValente: I have another problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780449/show-data-after-post-with-angularjs Now when I press the button, I get this error message: Error: data is not defined, can you help me?

Comment: I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with the dependencies in your controller. The names you have as strings in the array don't match the arguments to your factory function.

This should work:

```
as.controller('Test', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'testFactory', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, testFactory)
{   
    $http.get($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/test/test')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.test = data;
        });

    $scope.form = {};

    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
        if(isValid) 
        {   
            testFactory.testFactoryMethod(function($http) {
                $scope.test = data;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your controller like this

```
as.controller('Test', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'testFactory', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, testFactory)
{
    ....
}
```